# How to generate getter setter for an jmsserializer entity

Tags: entity-framework, symfony

I have made an entity to import an XML document. I use JMS serializer to decode it. So made the following Enity.

```
class Image
{
    /**
     * @JMS\Type("string")
     */
    public $thumbnail_url;

    /**
     * @JMS\Type("string")
     */
    public $img_url;
}
```

Now I want to generate the getter and setters around it. Normally using the following command:

```
app/console doctrine:generate:entities MyBundle:Image
```

Only getting the following error:

> [RuntimeException]
>   Namespace "MyBundle\Entity\Image" does not contain any mapped
>   entities.

How can this be solved?

Comment: I believe `doctrine:generate:entities` takes the bundle as an agument, not the entity itself. And what do you mean by "generate getter and setter"? Any half-decent IDE can do that in a blink of an eye...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Doctrine Mapper to generate getter and setters, also as Jovan said any decent IDE can generate it for you.

Example with Netbeans [Generate getters and setters](https://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/entry/generate_constructor_getters_and_setters)

Also the use statment for Doctrine mapper

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
```

Comment: I have added the use statement, but same error. Is it not the problem that the used annotation is @JMS insteand the normal @ORM? I use phpstorm so maybe that IDE can generate it.

Comment: If you want a doctrine command to do anything for you, you'll have to use the Doctrine Mapping (you can define it by yml, by annotation etc.).
What kind of getter and setters are you expecting? Just the standard ones? Then simply use PhpStorms getter/setter function.